# how to create Android app and display results in tableview

Tags: javascript, android

hi I'm creating an app with 3 screens which each screen has to allow users to navigate to the other by the form of buttons like for example the first screen contains different languages so in this case when u click at any language it has to take u to screen two which contains different scenarios when u click on any of the scenarios lets say for example "family " it has to open the last screen where it will display examples of the scenarios in table View.. .and suggestion on how I can solve this

codes bellow are the codes for the final screen where i have to display results in table form..so i tried to design the table in XML..but it gives out errors i don't know where i got it wrong..oh and this application is for android not IOS
the table has to have two columns.and again i would like to know how do i link other screens to display results on the tableView..like for instance when i click on one of the scenarios "family" from another screen it display the example of the selected scenario in tableView

```
  <TableRow>            <TextView                 android:text="Banana"></TextView>            <EditText                 ></EditText>            <EditText                ></EditText>        </TableRow>                      <TableRow>            <TextView                 android:text="Apple"></TextView>            <EditText                 ></EditText>            <EditText                ></EditText>        </TableRow>                                    <TableRow>            <TextView                 android:text="PEAR"></TextView>            <EditText                 ></EditText>            <EditText                ></EditText>        </TableRow>
```

Comment: Write some actual code, it might help.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean like Table Views on iOS.
I think you can use the ListView Layout http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

And in the method onListItemClick open new activity or change the fragment as you want.

Answer (score 0):

codes bellow are the codes for the final screen where i have to display results in table form..so i tried to design the table in XML..but it gives out errors i don't know where i got it wrong..oh and this application is for android not IOS
the table has to have two columns.and again i would like to know how do i link other screens to display results on the tableView..like for instance when i click on one of the scenarios "family" from another screen it display the example of the selected scenario in tableView

```
  <TableRow>            <TextView                 android:text="Banana"></TextView>            <EditText                 ></EditText>            <EditText                ></EditText>        </TableRow>                      <TableRow>            <TextView                 android:text="Apple"></TextView>            <EditText                 ></EditText>            <EditText                ></EditText>        </TableRow>                                    <TableRow>            <TextView                 android:text="PEAR"></TextView>            <EditText                 ></EditText>            <EditText                ></EditText>        </TableRow>
```